# Divs responsive CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put the divs like it appears on the image...
I am using bootstrap and I don't know if there are a trick to do that.
The divs bust be always centered if I reduce the screen size.

If you need more css please tell me...

[image]

[image]

HTML:

```
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                <div class="table-score">
                    <span class="score1">1</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 team-name1">Team 1</div>



                    <div class=" team-name2">Team 2</div><span class="col-sm-4  col-xs-4 score2">2</span>

                </div>
          </div>
```

Some CSS:

```
[.team-name1 {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 80px;
    width: 270px;
    height: 75px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #A30404 0%, #000000 50%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #A30404 0%, #000000 50%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #A30404 0%, #000000 50%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #A30404), color-stop(50, #000000));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A30404 0%, #000000 50%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #A30404 0%, #000000 50%);
    display: inline-block;

    z-index: 0;
}

.team-name2 {
    margin: 0 0 0 35px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 80px;
    width: 270px;
    height: 75px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: white;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #008A17 0%, #000000 50%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #008A17 0%, #000000 50%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #008A17 0%, #000000 50%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #008A17), color-stop(50, #000000));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #008A17 0%, #000000 50%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #008A17 0%, #000000 50%);
    display: inline-block;

    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yo7mu730/27/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add classes to both elements that you want to be responsive.

**col-sm-[1-12]**

> ex: col-sm-12 then when its reduced to small-device. the size will be
>   full-width.

`col-xs-[1-12]` for extra-small
`col-md-[1-12]` for medium-devices
`col-lg-[1-12]` for large-device.

you can refer to [Boostrap Components](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Edit: so meaning. you should put the `score1` and `score2` in separate `div` which has the `col` class. it should be like:

```
<div class="table-score">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-*6* col-sm-*6*">
    <span class="score1">1</span>
    <div class=" col-xs-10 team-name1">Team 1</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-*6* col-sm-*6*">
     <div class=" team-name2">Team 2</div><span class=" col-xs-10    score2">2</span>
</div>
 </div>
```

Note: from comments: put `table-score` outside the `col--` to avoid redundancy or pls see the comments below.

Comment: you are putting a <div class="col-*-*"> inside another <div class="col-*-*">... if you are using bootstrap follow his common guide lines...instead don't use it.
https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/css/#grid-example-basic

Comment: nope. clearly not. its inside the div which has the class `table-score` and only `table-score`. maybe because OP but his `table-score` elem inside the `col--`. but not mind. then we'll tell him or **I'll tell him not to**. pls find more mistake so we can help the OP more.

Comment: seriously...this: <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 team-name1">Team 1</div> is inside this: <div class="col-xs-*12* col-sm-*6*"> THIS IS NOT CORRECT

Comment: @Lorenzo: oh yes! thank you. it's from OP i just copied fixing now.

Comment: so basically you copied the OP code without checking it and vote down my answer only because you take it personally...ok...

Answer (score 3):

This would be your html structure using bootstrap:

```
<div class="table-score">
 <div class="col-xs-6">
   <!-- put your team 1 here -->
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6">
   <!-- put your team 2 here -->
 </div>
</div>
```

> **Explanation:** If viewed by mobile devices the two columns inside
>   division `table-score` will always be aligned because they divide the
>   screen 12 cols to 6 each.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your both class width to percentage `(%)` instead of `px`, as below,

```
.team-name1{
width:20%;
}
.team-name2{
width:20%;
}
```

This keeps both your class in center by reducing there width.

Answer (score -1):

The common structure of bootstrap is:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-*-*">*your first element*</div>
   <div class="col-*-*">*your second element*</div>
</div>
```

instead you are putting a col inside another col
some examples here:
https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/css/#grid-example-basic

Comment: I did not see this mentioned in the bootstrap?

Comment: like this? https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/css/#grid-example-basic

Comment: it says `.col-md-*` and the asterisk(*) is the size  not col-*size*